# Is there a way to read the form data of a post request within an iframe?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, forms, iframe, web-scraping

I'm trying to create a simple rails app that will automate some actions on a website that requires a sign-in.

Ideally, I'd prefer to not have to redo the sign-in and register-a-new-account functionality of the website, and to just have that inside an iframe in my web app. Is it possible to read the form data (ie: username and password) from a successful sign-in?

Or am I going about this the wrong way and there's a more practical way of doing this?

Comment: perhaps have a look at basic authentication or [oauth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth)

Comment: Forgot to mention, this website does not have an api.